# multiple if statements with similar pattern

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code which **works** but I am looking for a way to write it in a more pythonic way

```
    if item['merchant_1']=='Google' and not item['merchant_1_price']:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['merchant_1_link'],callback=self.parse_google,meta={'item': item})
    elif item['merchant_2']=='Google' and not item['merchant_2_price']:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['merchant_2_link'],callback=self.parse_google,meta={'item': item})

    elif item['merchant_1']=='Amazon' and not item['merchant_1_price']:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['merchant_1_link'],callback=self.parse_amazon,meta={'item': item})        
    elif item['merchant_2']=='Amazon' and not item['merchant_2_price']:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['merchant_2_link'],callback=self.parse_amazon,meta={'item': item})

    elif item['merchant_1']=='Ebay' and not item['merchant_1_price']:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['merchant_1_link'],callback=self.parse_ebay,meta={'item': item})
    elif item['merchant_2']=='Ebay' and not item['merchant_2_price']:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['merchant_2_link'],callback=self.parse_ebay,meta={'item': item})
    # another 30 similar elif statements for different sites

def parse_google(self,response):
    #code
def parse_amazon(self,response):
    #code
def parse_ebay(self,response):
    #code
```

I get two merchants (may or may not have a price) they will sure have a link,if any of them doesn't have a price it should yield their respective `parse_seller`(amazon,google,ebay,...). I wrote all the parse methods in similar pattern in order to write a better looking (Pythonic) code.
I am looking for a more compact way of writing those if statements

Comment: Consider creating a dict or object with keys/attributes like `name`, `link` and `price`

Comment: @MadPhysicist they are already in a dict called item, do you mean another dict?

Comment: You can make a nested `for` loop. Outer loop goes "Google", "Amazon", "eBay", etc. Inner loop goes "merchant_1", "merchant_2". Heck, you could even use `itertools.product`

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you show an example of how to do it using `itertools` ?

Comment: Not without knowing more about item

Comment: @MadPhysicist it is a Scrapy dictionary i.e `merchant_1=scrapy.Field()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to use a simple list.

```py
companies = ["Google", "Amazon", "Ebay"]
for company in companies:
    for i in range(1, 3):
        if item[f"merchant_{i}"] == company and not item[f"merchant_{i}_price"]:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=item[f"merchant_{i}_link"],callback=getattr(self, f"parse_{company.lower()}"),meta={'item': item})
```

Comment: No, because if you enumerate `companies` then each company will check against its own `index`. e.g - `Google` will check `merchant_0`, `Amazon` -> `merchant_1` etc.

Comment: this works perfectly for my question, However, this will only parse one of the two merchants (with no prices) with a priority for merchant1, how can I use this to parse both merchants? (i.e any merchant with no price will go to its respective parse_seller)

Comment: I'm not sure what `item` contains. Do you mean you want to loop over `merchant_1`, 2, 3, 4 etc. ?

Comment: assume I have two merchants (with no prices), this will only yield to merchant one (which was my main question) being parsed right?

how can I make it so after merchant1 is parsed,merchant2 will be parsed as well ?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Wasn't that the purpose of your `elif`? Anyway, you're not breaking after the `yield` - Meaning that the loop will keep running on all merchants if you use `yield` correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194556/discussion-between-hadesfv-and-adamgold).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more pythonic, 
but you could reorganize item a little bit:
right now you have:

```
item = { merchant1 : Google,
         merchant2 : Amazon,
         merchant_1_price: XXX,
         merchant_2_price : XXX,
         merchant_1_link : url1,
         merchant_2_link : url2,
}
```

You could change it by something like:

```
item = { merchants: [Google, Amazon],
         prices : [xxx,xxx],
         links : [url1, url2]
}
```

Google and Amazon being Merchant objects which would be defined by a name and a specific parse method
and then you just have to iterate over it:

```
for index,merchant in enumerate( item['merchants'] ):
    if not item['prices'][index]:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=item['links'][index],callback=merchant.parse,meta={'item': item})
```

Of course you have to set non-existing prize with something like 0 or None.

Here is an example on how to bind your Merchant object with a specific parse_method:

```
class Merchant:

    def __init__(self, name, parse_method):
        self.name = name
        self.parse_method = parse_method

    def parse(self,data):
        return self.parse_method(data)


def parse_method_1(data):
    return data.split(":")

def parse_method_2(data):
    return data.split(",")

google = Merchant("Google", parse_method_1)
print(google.parse("hello:world"))

amazon = Merchant("Amazon", parse_method_2)
print(google.parse("hello,world"))
```

Comment: `callback=merchant.parse` how will this address each parse method?

Comment: I have update the answer, so you can see it. Basically you bind your specific parsing_function with the object's  parse method at your object instanciation :)